# Perl: what kind of data should i feed to delcampe API?

Tags: perl, soap

I write soap-client based on Delcampe API. Simple methods work fine, but functions with need on complex data give me an error message like "You must send item's data!". Based on PHP example [here](http://code.google.com/p/delcampe-api-client/wiki/updateItem#Code_example_%28PHP%29) i thought, that data should be either hash or hashref, but both give me error mentioned before.

Sample script i use:

```
use 5.010;
use SOAP::Lite;
use SOAP::WSDL;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $API_key = 'xyz';
my $service = SOAP::Lite->service('http://api.delcampe.net/soap.php?wsdl');
my $return = $service->authenticateUser($API_key);

if ($return->{status}) {
    my $key = $return->{data};
    my %data = (description => 'updated description');
    my $response = $service->updateItem($key, 123456, \%data);

    if ($response->{status}) {
        say Dumper $response->{data};
    } else {
        say $response->{errorMsg};
    } 
} else {
    say "no: " . $return->{status};
}
```

So, what kind of data structure should i use instead of `%data` or how could i debug the SOAP-envelope, which is produced as request? (PHP code based on example works fine)

**ADDITION**

with `use SOAP::Lite qw(trace);` igot SOAP envelope too:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap-enc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://api.delcampe.net/soap.php">
    <soap:Body>
        <tns:updateItem>
            <token xsi:type="xsd:string">secret_one</token>
            <id_item xsi:type="xsd:int">123456</id_item>
            <arrData xsi:nil="true" xsi:type="soap-enc:Array" />
        </tns:updateItem>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

As seen above, there is no bit of data sent. I tried data also as string, array and arrayref. Maybe it is bug of `SOAP::Lite`?

Comment: Have you tried including the `personal_reference` and `title` keys in `%data`?  The PHP example sets all 3, and the docs don't make it clear whether they're optional.

Comment: @cjm, i tried changing only description with PHP too, and it worked.

Comment: Standard HTTP debugging techniques apply. Use Wireshark to compare request/response pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you'd try to replace

my %data = (description => 'updated description');

with

my $data = SOAP::Data->name(description => 'updated description');

We have similar issues when working on our SOAP API, and it was solved by something like that, wrapping complex data into SOAP::Data. So I hope this'll help. )

**UPDATE:**

The previous advice didn't help: looks like it's indeed the SOAP::Lite bug, which ignores the 'soap-enc:Array' definition in WSDL file whatsoever.

Have finally found a workaround, though. It's not pretty, but as a final resort it may work.

First, I've manually downloaded the WSDL file from Delcampe site, saved it into local directory, and referred to it as ...

```
my $service = SOAP::Lite->service('file://...delcampe.wsdl')
```

... as absolute path is required.

Then I've commented out the 'arrData line' within WSDL updateItem definition.

And, finally, I've made this:

```
my $little_monster = SOAP::Data->name(arrData => 
  \SOAP::Data->value((
    SOAP::Data->name(item => 
        \SOAP::Data->value(
          SOAP::Data->name(key => 'personal_reference'),
          SOAP::Data->name(value => 'Some Personal Reference')->type('string'),
        )
     ),
     SOAP::Data->name(item => 
        \SOAP::Data->value(
          SOAP::Data->name(key => 'title'),
          SOAP::Data->name(value => 'Some Amazing Title')->type('string'),
        )
     ),
     # ... 
  ))
)->type('ns1:Map');
```

... and, I confess, successfully released it into the wilderness by ...

```
$service->updateItem($key, 123456, $little_monster);
```

... which, at least, generated more-o-less likable Envelope.

I sincerely hope that'll save at least some poor soul from banging head against the wall as much as I did working on all that. )

Comment: This should work - I have often been tripped up similarly, see the documentation for SOAP::Data for details on how to make and control more complicated data structures (http://search.cpan.org/~mkutter/SOAP-Lite-0.714/lib/SOAP/Data.pod)

Comment: It looked promising, but no, same "You must send item's data!" and arrData is empty.

Comment: Based on your suggestion and `SOAP::Data` docs i formed it this way: http://pastebin.com/XhyZaM4x. It did not work. Frankly, i don't think it would help, because other arguments i give to method `updateItem` are basic string and basic int, but when i debug the request envelope, they are properly formed as XML. So why should 3rd element already be formed as SOAP/XML? That is the idea of `SOAP::Lite` module to form them for me based on WSDL-file rules. AFAIU

Comment: This workaround has a bottleneck (local copy of WSDL), but it does what needed. I appreciate your contribution. Thank you!