# Perl wsdl webservice call

Tags: perl, soap, wsdl

I am new to perl webservice call.

I am calling a wsdl webservice function and I am getting the response as 400 bad request error. I tried and googled many sites but could not get successful. Please help me in solving this issue. Below is my code.

```
use SOAP::Lite;
my $lite = SOAP::Lite -> service('http://localhost:8080/service.svc?wsdl');
my $arg1 ="SRC";
my $arg2 = "ARG";
my @arg3 = ('test1','test2','test3');
my @res = $lite->Func($arg1,$arg2,@arg3);
print "@res";
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336161/perl-what-kind-of-data-should-i-feed-to-delcampe-api) and seemed that `SOAP::Lite` may have a bug concerning handling complex data structures.

Whatever, if your SOAP method (`Func`) needs 3 arguments, the last one should be reference to array.

Also, with `use SOAP::Lite qw(trace)` you could debug request envelope.

Comment: tried passing as reference but still says bad request error itself...:(

Comment: @Naga: So next move i sugegst is to debug your request envelope. I bet that third argument is missing from envelope. This may be one reason for bad request.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not restrict at SOAP::Lite, I will request you to please have a look at [XML::Compile::SOAP::Client](http://search.cpan.org/~markov/XML-Compile-SOAP-2.26/lib/XML/Compile/SOAP/Client.pod)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much of a difference there is between a WSDL and an ASMX web service.  If not much, try this code sample which works for me.

```
  my $soap = SOAP::Lite
    -> uri('http://foo.com')
    -> on_action( sub { join '/', 'http://foo.com', $_[1] } )
    -> proxy('http://foo/services/GetEmailAddress/Service.asmx');

  my $method = SOAP::Data->name('GetEmailAddress')
    ->attr({xmlns => 'http://foo.com/'});

  my @params = ( SOAP::Data->name(username => $user) ); 
  my $email = $soap->call($method => @params)->result;
```

Input is a username, output is an email address.  The ASMX web service was created in .NET 3, I believe.

Everything I know about how this works I learned from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995764.aspx.

Comment: tried the above...getting the error like this "cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None)"